# Addition of an organization in Hyperledger-fabric blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am adding new org I am getting this error

> Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to
>   connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection:
>   context deadline exceeded

while doing this

> peer channel fetch 0 mychannel.block -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c
>   $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA

Comment: I would recommend adding more info like 1) were you trying some example? 2) whats your setup? 3) are all the containers live when the error happens?

Answer (score 1):

Error resolved prblem was containers were with different network it works if all the conatiners are in same network

Comment: Hi, I am having the same error as you. How do you ensure that all containers are part of the same network? I am running the balance-transfer example and am trying to add a new organization to the network (org3), but it seems like the containers created for Org3 cannot connect to the orderer. Thanks,

Comment: @himi64 I am also having the same problem. Can you or any of you provide the solution here..Thanks in advance

Comment: @GeoFresher as I have already mentioned make sure all the containers are on the same container network

Comment: @DarshuBc you were right.. I forgot to add this `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=net` due to which docker-compose was creating network using default driver appending  XYZ_network_name. The initial setup for the first Org was set up using the same.